# Android: Unable to delete data from the database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-sqlite, onlongclicklistener

I want to delete a particular row from the listview, in which the data is being populated from the database. On `setOnItemLongClickListener` I have been able to delete the data from the listview, but when I restart my activity I can see that the row which I have deleted is there because on `onCreate()` I fetch the data from the database.

Here what I have done:

MainActivity.java

```
db = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);
    showing_history
            .setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                        View arg1, final int pos, final long id) {
                    final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            MainActivity.this);
                    b.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                    b.setMessage("Delete this from history?");
                    b.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {

                                    HistoryNamesList.remove(pos);
                                    ((BaseAdapter) mHistoryListAdapter)
                                            .notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    del(pos);
                                }
                            });
                    b.setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    b.show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

My delete method in MainActivity.java:

```
private void del(int j) {

    if (db.deleteTitle(j))
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(this, "Delete failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    db.close();

}
```

My delete query in AndroidOpenDbHelper.java

```
public boolean deleteTitle(long rowId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(TABLE_NAME_HISTORY, ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}
```

Again, I'm able to delete the data from the listview but not from the database. Please help me in overcoming this problem.

Comment: any, like, errors, stacktrace, log at all ?

Comment: You may want to take a look into ContentProviders. Post your onCreate method.

Comment: position is not id. also, what is deleteTitle ?

Comment: instead of del(pos) use del(id);

Comment: No errors at all, just getting toast saying Delete failed. del(id), will not help is getting database data cleaned.

Comment: Your if statements are a bit vague to me... Why is there a condition if (db.deleteTitle(j))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first ur get all row id's using following code

```
private int[] mRowId;
    dba.open();
        Cursor cr=dba.fetchData();
        cr.moveToFirst();
int i=0;
while(!cr.isAfterLast())
        {
mRowId[i]==cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex("colname"));
i++;
cr.moveToNext();

}
```

on listview item click

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
         db.deleteTitle(mRowId[pos]);
            return true;
        }

public void deleteTitle(int rowid) {
        try {
            database.execSQL("DELETE FROM  TableName" + " where columnname="
                    + rowid + ";");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is fetchData() method, can you please share that too.

Comment: public Cursor fetchData() {
  try {
   return database.query(TableName, null, null, null, null, null,
     null);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   return null;
  }
 }

Comment: @sai-  Can you please properly format your answer, because some of the variables are missing, and this is becoming very confusing to me. Please can you do that, so that I can finish this thing.

Comment: Sry I can't, this is just a code snippet for what I'm doing. That will be a problem for me. Can't you help me here?

Answer (score 0):

try using db.raw query rather than db.delete... i hope this can help you..

Comment: The query is working fine checked with the command propmpt adb shell, but I can't delete from the code.

Comment: Have you tried using this SQLiteDatabase db; instead of SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
public void deleteTableRow(int rowid) {
        try {
            database.execSQL("DELETE FROM  TableName" + " where columnname="
                    + rowid + ";");
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are saying the same thing in different way, anyways tried that, not working getting same Toast as Delted Failed.

Comment: pull your database file and check it in Sq Lite browser once.table row deleting or not,other wise execute this query in sq lite browser once.

Comment: Ya, all the query is running perfectly fine, but I'm not able to delete on longpress of the button.

Comment: ur r sending pos i thing pos is no ur respected  row id so  getting same Toast as Delted Failed,first u save all row id in an array element,then pass this array element using pos like this arr[pos].

Comment: Can you please guide me through that, I have tried all methods nothing is working for m.

Comment: check i am posting one more answer